# SFINAE with invalid function-type or array-type parameters?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, sfinae

Please consider this code:

```
template<typename T>
char (&f(T[1]))[1];

template<typename T>
char (&f(...))[2];

int main() { char c[sizeof(f<void()>(0)) == 2]; }
```

I expected it doing SFINAE and chosing the second overload, since substitution of `T` into `T[1]` yields

```
 void [1]()
```

Which is an invalid type, of course. Adjustment of parameter types (array->pointer) is done after substituting template parameters into function parameters and checking for valid resulting types like 14.8.2 [temp.deduct] describes.

But both comeau and GCC fail to compile the above. Both with different diagnostics.

Comeau says:

> "ComeauTest.c", line 2: error: array of functions is not allowed `char (&f(T[1]))[1];`

GCC says (version `4.3.3`):

> error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array `c`

Meaning, GCC does not fail to substitute, but it chooses the first overload of `f`, returning a `sizeof` of 1, instead of failing to substitute it up front like Comeau.

What compiler is right and is my code valid at all? Please refer to or quote the proper Standard section in your answer. Thanks!

---

**Update**: The Standard itself contains such an example in the list at `14.8.2/2`. I don't know, why I overlooked it first:

```
template <class T> int f(T[5]);
int I = f<int>(0);
int j = f<void>(0); // invalid array
```

While the example is only informative, it shows the intention of all those mysterious paragraphs and seems to show the code above should work and reject the first overload.

Comment: litb asking for a standards clarification is a contradiction :)

Comment: i asked the same on usenet, but posted the question here too, so that it can be archived on SO and people will find it when searching on SO. Link to usenet: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/78f8cd8cf27778e3

Comment: I thought litb IS the standard...?

Comment: Well, a quick browse through the standard confirms Comeau's complaint, at least. According to 8.3.4, arrays of functions are not allowed. I only skimmed your code though (in a bit of a hurry atm), so it's entirely possible I've missed something vital ;)

Comment: I think I'll just wait for litb to answer this...

Comment: I have noted this day just because of litb asked a C++ related question and I am witnessing it. I feel so special! It is like attending Elvis's concert!

Comment: I think that 14.8.2 [temp.deduct] isn't relevant here as you provided an explicit template parameter. I'm still reading 14.8.3 [temp.over], though.

Comment: hmm. I found something interesting i overlooked before at 12.8.2/4 : "The resulting substituted **and adjusted** function type is used as the type of the function template for template argument deduction. When all template arguments have been deduced, all uses of template parameters in nondeduced contexts are replaced with the corresponding deduced argument values. If the substitution results in an invalid type, as described above, type deduction fails." (highlight ** by me). Looks like i checks for type-validness *after* substituting, not before.

Comment: it saying "If a substitution in a template parameter or in the
function type of the function template results in an invalid type, type deduction fails. " and refering to "the function type of the function template" seems to refer to that paragraph 4, which defines the type as being the type *after* adjustment. I was confused by "After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type adjustments..." in paragraph 3. But it is not refering to type-checking at all.

Comment: Charles, paragraph 2 of 14.8.2 still talks about explicitly given template arguments. Deduction of them inferred from a call to it starts at 14.8.2.1

Comment: But anyway, it says "If substitution results in an invalid type...", which does not explicitly include adjustments. Confusing! But anyway, i'm not sure which compiler is right. Is it required for a compiler to diagnose an invalid type *before* parameter-type adjustment but *after* substitution of template-parameters into function-parameter types? I feel it is, but i wonder whether the Standard is explicit about that?

Comment: You're right, I read it as only applying to cases where some template arguments are explicit and others are 'deduced' but I suppose it could still apply to the 'all explicit' case when there's nothing left to deduce.

Comment: If it really looks for invalid function types *after* adjustments of function parameters types, then the type would be char(&(void(*)()))[1] and would be totally valid it seems (A). On another side 8.3.5 may fail to adjust, because it's not a valid array-type to begin with, so it may stay char(&(void[1]()))[1] or 8.3.5 may error out hard (B). I think Comeau interprets it like (B) and GCC interprets it like (A). In any case, in my opinion the Standard should be more clear about what should be done.

Comment: I am not convinced by the example TBH.  They're not normative anyway - but that being said, I think the subtlety in declaration matching would not have been obvious when the example was first added.  As per my answer - I don't think the standard actually says when parameter decay takes place, and it *must* be happening for some cases in order to match declarations.

Comment: Richard, thinking about it, i come to the conclusion that it can't decay. The Standard says it decays array types. But void[1]() is not an array type (but it's not a valid type). I've read in defect reports that this is in line what the committee was thinking of too: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#478 I'm not sure at all, and I'm close to submitting a issue report asking them to state normatively what to do in such a case.

Comment: @litb:  My points relates to a decay on the "dependent type".  In order to match declarations and definitions the compiler applies the adjustments to 8.3.5 to the dependent parameter types.  Therefore, at least for decl matching, "T [10]" will be decayed to "T *".  The only question is what type does the function then specialize, the original declaration "foo(T[10])" or the decayed declaration "foo(T*)".  What if there are multiple declarations with different "compatible" types - I've added some examples to my answer below.

Comment: @Richard, i see now what you mean. Well the Standard says that first it substitutes the explicit template arguments into the function parameter types, and then, it adjusts the resulting types. The then resulting function-type is used for template argument deduction. After that, all template arguments then known are inserted into each place where they are used and checked for invalid types again. If any invalid type is generated, then a type-deduction occurs and template argument deduction fails as a consequence.

Comment: I feel dumb, but what does the ellipsis mean in the code?

Comment: @rlbond, the ellipsis eats anything you pass to it. it's the C-style variadic function parameter thingy. as this all happens within sizeof, things are not really passed, but rather it's simulated. So we use ellipsis, since it has the worst priority when overload resolution compares conversion sequences. If the other function can be called, it will be called. But if not, the ellipsis function will be selected, and the other function is ignored (sfinae)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A small note, although very rare, I have found some occasions where I
believe that the Comeau compiler has it wrong - although, these
occasions are so rare that its always worth double and triple
checking your assumptions!

I may have a reason for the behaviour of g++.  I'm not sure its
specified exactly when parameter types are adjusted:

Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  void bar (T[10]);
};

template<typename T>
void A<T>::bar (T*)
{
}
```

The definition of 'bar' is legal, as "T[10]" decays to "T*".  I do
not see anything in the standard that prohibits the compiler from
performing the adjustments of 8.3.5 against the template declaration,
and it also improves performance when it comes to overload matching.

Applying this to your example, g++ might be treating it as:

```
template<typename T>
char (&f( T* ))[1];

template<typename T>
char (&f(...))[2];

int main() { char c[sizeof(f<void()>(0)) == 2]; }
```

In the above, the substituted parameter is a legal pointer to
function, rather than an array of functions.

So, the question for me is - is if there is something that prohibts
the adjustments for the function parameters (8.3.5) twice?

Personally, I think it makes sense to allow the adjustments to happen
twice since otherwise it complicates the matching of function template
overloads

In conclusion, I think its valid for g++ to select the first overload
based on how it treates decaying array parameters, and Comeau is wrong
not to have a deduction failure for the array of functions.

Of course this now means that (if Comeau was fixed) then each compiler
would choose a different overload and would still be standards
compliant! :(

**EDIT:**

Just to illustrate my point, consider the following code:

```
template <typename T> void foo ( T * );
template <typename T> void foo ( T * const );
template <typename T> void foo ( T [] );
template <typename T> void foo ( T [10] );
template <typename T> void foo ( T [100] );

void bar () 
{
  foo < void() > ( 0 );
}
```

Here, foo has been declared and redeclared several times.  Which declaration, and so which parameter type, should the compiler apply the rules listed in 14.8.2?

My point is that the standard doesn't say anything about the above.  I would also go as far as to say that any wording on this would have to leave it as either "undefined" or "implementation defined" behaviour.

Comment: hmm good point about multiple declarations. I've no idea about what is chosen there, actually. Ill have to look for it later. Thanks for your help dude :) I also think now it would be a good idea just to say it first decays (using "T as element/function type"), then substitutes, then decays again.

Comment: The more I think of this, the more I feel that it deserves to have a core issue opened for it.  I tried some examples with Comeau and it seems to be the first function type which is used to perform the checking always.  However, this is not sensible, as it implies that the order in which declarations are seen is important - something that should not be the case.

Comment: Another possibility would be to state that two template declarations that have identical parameter-type-lists are funtionally-equivalent (defined at 14.6.6.1/6 - so far only for expressions, not yet for parameter types). But saying they are equivalent if the non-modified parameter-type-list's are the same. Then, if the declarations of a function template are not equivalent, but functional equivalent, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: I think you provided an important insight: GCC is correct, since if the declaration used T[1], GCC is allowed to change it to T*, by the rules of 14.5.5.1 [temp.over.link] - but nothing forbids comeau to not change it, since after all both are equivalent - but i think comeau should still not fail hard - but make it a deduction failure. Since this is obviously a contradiction (two equivalent declaration fail one time, but not the other time?), i agree with you that this is a bug in the standard, and accept your stuff. thanks so much for your insight :)

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly enough - this does work in VS2008.  I don't think that's necessarily evidence for it being correct behaviour or not though...

Visual Studio is interpretting

```
char (&f(T[1]))[1];
```

as a function that takes an array of size 1 of T, and returns a reference to an array of chars of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to describe the process of template argument deduction as I understand it from reading the standard.

1. Explicit template arguments are checked as described in 14.8.2/2.
2. The resulting function signature is adjusted as per 8.3.5 (i.e. array to pointer decay is performed).
3. Implicit template arguments are deduced as per 14.8.2.1 (this is performed on a partially substituted signature from step 2).

The deduction for the first overload fails in step 1, the overload resolution therefore returns the second overload. I don't believe the program is ill-formed.

Comment: a deduction failure should not however result in a compilation failure. 14.8.3/1 says "If, for a given function template,
argument deduction fails, no such function is added to the set of candidate functions for that template.". Nowhere it is stated that such a deduction failure results in a program being ill-formed.

Comment: Yeah this is what i think about it too. Looks like comeau fails within 8.3.5 trying to adjust void[1]() to void(*)(), and then noting that void[1]() is an invalid type, not knowing that it is within a type deduction process. If it were to allow to error out at that stage, it would have to error out for other invalid types too, i suspect, like for template<typename T> char (&f(T(*)[1]))[1]; but there, it's actually causing an SFINAE error (no real diagnostic, but just using the second overload).