# Is sizeof(E) an idiomatic SFINAE technique to check if E is a valid expression?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae

I just found out how to check if `operator<<` is provided for a type.

```
template<class T> T& lvalue_of_type();
template<class T> T  rvalue_of_type();

template<class T>
struct is_printable
{
    template<class U> static char test(char(*)[sizeof(
        lvalue_of_type<std::ostream>() << rvalue_of_type<U>()
    )]);
    template<class U> static long test(...);

    enum { value = 1 == sizeof test<T>(0) };
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool, value> type;
};
```

Is this trick well-known, or have I just won the metaprogramming Nobel prize? ;)

EDIT: I made the code simpler to understand and easier to adapt with two global function template declarations `lvalue_of_type` and `rvalue_of_type`.

Comment: With VC++ it appears that `is_printable<X>::value` is true for any X, and with Comeau Online it appears to be false for any X.

Comment: With g++, I get 1 for `is_printable<int>::value` and 0 for `is_printable<std::vector<int> >::value`, so it works fine for me.

Comment: So it works on 1 out of 3 compilers...

Comment: That's shorter:
```template <typename X, typename Y>
static auto check(X& x, Y& y) -> decltype(x << y);```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a well known technique, I'm afraid :-)

The use of a function call in the `sizeof` operator instructs the compiler to perform argument deduction and function matching, at compile-time, of course. Also, with a template function, the compiler also instantiates a concrete function from a template. However, this expression does does not cause a function call to be generated. It's well described in [SFINAE Sono Buoni](http://www.semantics.org/once_weakly/w02_SFINAE.pdf) PDF.

Check other [C++ SFINAE examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982808/c-sfinae-examples).

Answer (score 1):

It is just a combination of two well-known tricks. SFINAE says 'substitution failure is not an error' - that's exactly what you did. Using `sizeof` to let the compiler substitute template arguments into an expression without actually executing it is also common.

Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be an idiomatic technique, but it's been completely obsoleted by newer language versions.

#### `std::declval` <sup>(C++11)</sup>

```cpp
template<class T> T& lvalue_of_type();
template<class T> T  rvalue_of_type();
```

has been superseded by `std::declval<T&>()` for lvalues, and `std::declval<T>()` for xvalues. It's worth noting that `std::declval` never returns a value, in part because this would require a non-private destructor.

#### `requires` expressions and `concept`s <sup>(C++20)</sup>

This technique has also been obsoleted.
To check whether the expression ...

> ```cpp
> stream << object; // where stream is std::ostream&, and object is T&
> ```

... is valid, you could write a `concept`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept printable = requires (std::ostream& stream, T& object) {
    stream << object;
    { stream << object; } -> std::same_as<std::ostream&>;
};
```