# C++ Callback -- How to decouple the call back type

Tags: c++, templates, types, callback, decouple

For example, in the following pseudo code, Class B need to call A::Action() through B::m_cb member.
The objective is, how to make a general, non-template Callback class, so "B" does not have to be a template, and the "CallBack" can hold any kind of function signature.

I ever use such code before, but now I can not find that implementation. All I remember is:
- the "CallBack" itself is not a template, but it contains member template
- the helper function template make_callback will instantiate CallBack object

Can anyone give a poiinter?

```
Class A
{
public:
   void Action(){//...};
};

class CallBack
{
   //...
   // CallBack it self it is a NOT a template
   // It can wrap member template though
};

class B
{
public:
   void SetCallback(CallBack to){
      m_cb = to;
   }
   void do_something()
   {
      //...
      m_cb.Execute();
      //...
   }

private:
   CallBack m_cb;

};

int main()
{
   A obj1;
   CallBack cb = make_callback(&obj1, &A::Action);
   B obj2;
   obj2.SetCallback(cb);
   //....
   obj2.do_something();
}
```

Here is the sample code I got from this same website. 
I tried to improved it a little bit, so it can tolerate arbitrary call back function's return type. But it still can not handle arbitrary number of arguments, like in line 18. Also, , T is the pointer to member function, which should be depend on C. I don't know how to enforce this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// INTERNAL CLASSES

class CallbackSpecBase
{
  public:
    virtual ~CallbackSpecBase() {}
    virtual void operator()(...) const = 0;
};

template<class C, class T>
class CallbackSpec : public CallbackSpecBase
{
  public:
    CallbackSpec(C& o, T m) : obj(o), method(m) {}
/*line 18*/    void operator()(...) const { (&obj->*method)(); } // how to pass "..." into method(...)

  private:
    C& obj;
    T method;
};

// PUBLIC API

class Callback
{
  public:
    Callback() {}

    void operator()() { (*spec)(); }

    template<class C, class T>
      void set(C& o, T m) { spec.reset(new CallbackSpec<C, T>(o, m)); }

  private:
    std::auto_ptr<CallbackSpecBase> spec;
};

// TEST CODE

class Test
{
  public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "Working" << std::endl; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "Like a charm" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  Callback c;
  c.set(t, &Test::foo);
  c();
  c.set(t, &Test::bar);
  c();
}
```

Comment: Tip: [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) already offers this kind of functionality so it spares you having to implement it yourself.

Comment: Can Boost.Bind handle arbitrary callback function signature? like arbitrary types, and arbitrary number of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, because a callback has to be a template, unless you want to pass a parameter through `void*` (which is totally crazy idea in my opinion).

I asked a similar question : [What is wrong with this variadic templates example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656691/what-is-wrong-with-this-variadic-templates-example)

One of answers gave a complete solution :

```
#include <memory>

template< typename R, typename ... Args >
class CallbackBase
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr< CallbackBase< R, Args... > >
            CallbackPtr;

    virtual ~CallbackBase()
    {
    }
    virtual R Call(  Args ... args) = 0;
};

template< typename R, typename ... Args >
class FunctionCallback : public CallbackBase< R, Args... >
{
public:
    typedef R (*funccb)(Args...);

    FunctionCallback( funccb  cb_ ) : 
        CallbackBase< R, Args... >(),
        cb( cb_ )
    {
    }
    virtual ~FunctionCallback()
    {
    }
    virtual R Call(Args... args)
    {
      return cb( args... );
    }
private:
  funccb cb;
};

template < typename R, typename ...Args >
typename CallbackBase< R, Args... >::CallbackPtr
    MakeCallback( R (*cb)(Args...)  )
{
    typename CallbackBase< R, Args... >::CallbackPtr
        p( new FunctionCallback< R, Args... >( cb )
);
    return p;
}

bool Foo_1args( const int & t)
{
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    auto cbObj = MakeCallback( & Foo_1args );
}
```

Hope it helps. If you hate templates, you can always use a typedef.

Comment: Thanks. I found another sample code, which is similar, but I believe is better. The public API is template free. What I am still missing is how to handle variable length argument list of the callback function. I'll post that sample code as another answer to this question. Please check

Comment: I can not answer my own question within 8 hours. I've pasted the code to the end of my question. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `std::function` (C++0x) /`boost::function`. These use type-erasure to make functions act like first-class objects. You can do something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void Action() {//...};
};

class B
{
public:
    template <typename Func>
    void SetCallback(Func func) {
        m_cb = func;
    }

    void do_something() {
        m_cb(); // whatever function
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_cb; // anything callable with no arguments
};

int main()
{
    A obj1;
    B obj2;

    obj2.SetCallback(make_callback(&obj1, &A::Action));
    // or:
    obj2.SetCallback(std::bind(&obj1, &A::Action)); // or boost::bind

    obj2.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just found a sample code can do this in standard c++. What I still can not do is to deal with arbitrary function signature. Seems that will require to pass "..." into another function: like this: void f(...){ g(...); // pass f()'s args into g(). Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @John: I don't understand your question. You need to narrow down what you're trying to do and come up with a real use case, not keep asking hypotheticals.

Comment: @John Crane: The signature must be fixed at compile-time. Even with variadic templates, you can still only vary them at compile-time. C++ will not support run-time variant arguments- they must be statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a callback mechanism based on this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CPPCallback.aspx

With that implementation you can either use *global functions*, *static member functions* or *non-static member functions* as callbacks.

The article describes how to create delegate objects as functors for all of these types. Your `class B` could have a delegate object as member and a method for registering a callback function and a method for calling it. Neither `class B` nor your callback functions have to be templated! The delegate objects contain an object pointer in case a non-static member function is used as callback and a pointer to a templated static wrapper function. In this wrapper function the function pointer to your callback function is stored. It is either invoked directly or before bound to the passed object pointer.

```
class B
{
  public:
    void SetCallback(CDelegate f_Delegate)
    {
      m_Delegate = f_Delegate;
    }
    static void do_something()
    {
      //...
      m_Delegate();
      //...
    }

  private:
    static CDelegate m_Delegate;
};
```

*Update:*

The mechanism is also described here:
[5 years later, is there something better than the "Fastest Possible C++ Delegates"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298408/5-years-later-is-there-something-better-than-the-fastest-possible-c-delegates)