# BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT on MSVC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost

I am using boost 1.45.0 and have some code that does the following:

```
template <typename T = some_type, std::size_t N = 3> class my_class {
    public:
typedef T value_type;
        ...
        ...
        my_class(value_type i0) {BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(N==1); m_data[0]=i0;}
    protected:
T m_data[N]; 
            //!< The internal data array used to store indices
}
```

This generates the following error on MS VC++ 2010 (which I understand has implemented static_assert as 
one of their major changes) and no errors on MS VC++ 2008:

```
 error C2338: N==1
```

Likewise, there are other errors at some other BOOST_STATIC_ASSERTs in the same code (left out for brevity).

I also tried replacing with the static_assert from VC++ but get a similar build error (prints out the message string).

What workaround exists for this?

Comment: What's the code that instantiates `func` that should trigger the error?

Comment: Well, `N` doesn't equal 1, so what do you expect?

Comment: `static_assert` fails when the condition is *false*, not when it is true. Maybe that's where your confusion comes from? Just to be clear, `3==1` is false, hence it fails.

Comment: thanks @GMan: I see your point; but somehow I feel there might be a fix to this. Isn't this type of usage covered by SFINAE? Plus it builds fine on MS VC++ 2008 (albeit I was using boost 1.39.0 then)

Comment: The static assert is doing what it should be. You're checking that N == 1, but you set its default value to 3. So if any my_class instance with a default template paramater comes along, it should trigger that assertion. What are you trying to do?

Comment: From his code you can't tell what N is. You just assumed he leaves that parameter as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of static assertions. Static assertions are meant to state properties that *must* be true for the code to compile. If what you want is to write a function that won't be generated unless some condition is true but not fail compilation, you need to use [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3407633/46642).

```
// don't forget to #include <type_traits> for std::enable_if

template <std::size_t N1 = N>
my_class(value_type i0, typename std::enable_if<N1==1>::type* = 0)
{m_data[0]=i0;}
```

Comment: @Fernandes.. you might be on to something. Let me try this and get back with you. I think you nailed it.

Comment: @Fernandes, I tried this out but now I am getting a build error: error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test>'

Comment: @user545591 : That's what happens if N != 1 and you have no alternative constructor overloads to call. I.e., the whole purpose is to make the overload containing the `enable_if` ineligible during overload resolution if the condition is false, so you need some other overload to call in that circumstance.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot something. Seems like you need to make the constructor a template for this to work. I'll edit.

Comment: @ildjarn: I do have other overloads. Just haven't listed them there. There's a constructor that takes 2 arguments and then 3 as well as one that takes none. So if N != 1, are you saying that the compiler should give the error above your comment?

Comment: @user545591 : You need another _eligible_ overload (at a minimum, one that has the same effective arity); otherwise, yes, the error you posted in the comment is absolutely expected.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : He's using VC++ 2010, which does not support default function template arguments, so your code as-is won't work.

Comment: @Fernandes: Now I run into another error essentially as ildjarn describes: error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template

Comment: @Fernandes & all: No problem, thanks all. Learnt something new after all.