# No matching function for call to for a generic function

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm having some difficulties with the below generic function, I want this function to take 2 iterators and a value. The function should iterate between the 2 iterators and check for any occurrences of the value and count the occurrences. But I get the following error:

> no matching function for call to 'count_c(int, std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator)'

```
 template<typename Container>
 int count_c(Container i, typename Container::iterator &start, typename Container::iterator &end){
     typedef typename Container::iterator Iter;
     int count;
     for(Iter p = start; p != end; p++){
       if((*p) == i){
       count = count + 1;
     }
     return count;
 }


int main(){
  vector<double> myv;
  myv.push_back(9);
  myv.push_back(10);
  count_c(9, myv.begin(), myv.end());
  return 0;
}
```

It's part of an exam question:

> Write a generic function count which:
>
> - Takes as parameters a value and two iterators of a container (where to start from and
>     where to finish in the container).
> - It uses the iterators to go through the elements of the container and count the occur-
>     rences of the value in the container.
> - Finally, it returns the number of occurrences of the value it has found.

The two iterators are not necessarily the same as what is returned by a con-
tainer’s begin() and end() methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't pass the iterators in by reference.

Why? Because you can't bind references to rvalue expressions, which `begin()` and `end()` are. Besides, there's not much point in doing so, as iterators are very small and faster to copy by value.

2) Use the iterator type, not the container.

`9` is not a container, and so lacks an iterator type. There is no reason to need the container, as iterators were designed to work without them. Some iterators don't even have a container, such as plain ol pointers. You can always call your function as `count_c<foo::iterator>(...)` if you want to specify the type of iterator.

```
 template<typename iter_t>
 int count_c(int i, iter_t start, iter_t end){
     int count = 0;
     for(iter_t p = start; p != end; p++){
      if((*p) == i){
      count = count + 1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialise `count`!

Answer (score 4):

First, you pass `9` (which is of type `int`) and that is what `Container` gets deduced as. Since `int` doesn't have a nested typedef `iterator`, [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633/explain-c-sfinae-to-a-non-c-programmer) kicks in. That removes the function from the overload set, and since you have no other function that could be chosen, you are left with no functions to call: the error.

Since this is for exam preparation, I'll only give a hint: Templatize on iterators and value type, not the container type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, one other question though. I'm passing  myv.begin(), myv.end() as my parameters. But how can I make my iterator point to any element in the vector?

Comment: @cody: If you mean you want to point it at a certain index, this will do: `iterator it_at_index = myv.begin() + index;`.