# C++ template typedef as template function argument

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't the compiler find a match for `read1`? I don't see the difference between `read1` and `read2`; is there a limitation for nested typedef templates like the one in the `Foo` class?

```
template<typename T>
class Handle{};

class Foo{
public:
    typedef Handle<Foo> Handle;
};


template<typename T>
void read1(typename T::Handle){}

template<typename T>
void read2(Handle<T>){}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo::Handle f1;    
    read1(f1);

    Foo::Handle f2;
    read2(f2);
}
```

G++ compiler output, (G++ 4.4.5)

```
g++ -c -I.  main1.cpp 
main1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main1.cpp:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘read1(Handle<Foo>&)’
```

Comment: I removed the redundant `Internal` namespace, keep examples concise.

Comment: With G++ 4.4.5 your edit break the code,  `g++ -c main.cpp 
main.cpp:8: error: declaration of ‘typedef class Handle<Foo> Foo::Handle’
main.cpp:3: error: changes meaning of ‘Handle’ from ‘class Handle<Foo>’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘read1(Handle<Foo>&)’`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo::Handle f1;    
read1(f1);
```

The type being passed to read1 is `Handle<Foo>`, not Foo.

Templates are not inheritance. `Handle<Foo>` is a distinct class that is not a Foo, so there is no `Handle<Foo>::Handle`.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T>
void read1(typename T::Handle)
{
}
```

First, you will never be able to call this function without providing an explicit template parameter like `read1<Foo>(f1)`. Read up on [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633/explain-c-sfinae-to-a-non-c-programmer).

Second, how should the compiler *ever* find out what `T` is? It would have to test all nested typedefs of all possible classes you could possibly ever write. Sounds impossible? It is.

Comment: It doesn't have to test every class you could possibly write; it need only test those classes defined at the point of the read1 call.  Possible (easy even, compared to some things required of the compiler to handle templates), but not done per the standard.

Comment: Why can find the argument like it does for read2? It just need to test Foo there aren't other types

Comment: It doesn't just have to test all classes defined at the point, but also all possible template instantiations (might be possible in template form though). But how would it resolve ambiguities? Normaly the programmer would have to fix those, but in this case some completely unrelated code change (different namespace and all) can lead to an ambiguity there, so having the programmer fix those isn't really an option. @José: It might only have to test foo in this simple example, but most scnearious are more complicated and language features which don't work most of the times aren't all that popular