# Template Function Specialisation C++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I need to implement algorithm, that recursively calculates the scalar product of two vectors using templates.

There is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, int Size>
T scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
{
    return a[Size - 1]*b[Size - 1] + (scalar_product<T, Size - 1>(a, b));
}

template<typename T>
T scalar_product<T, 0>(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b) // error!
{
    return a[0] * b[0];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(3, 1);
    std::vector<int> b(3, 3);

    std::cout << scalar_product<int, 3>(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use this specialisation `T scalar_product<T, 0>(...)`, I get error "**'scalar_product' : illegal use of explicit template arguments**". But if I remove it like this `T scalar_product(...)` compiler report that recursion is going to be infinite (because there is no specialisation,  as I understand).

There are a lot of questions of this type here, but I wasn't able to find useful answer. How can I specialize this function without using classes? Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Not related to your question but you can have a base case in your main recursive function that checks if size == 1, do this, else that.

Comment: I guess you are using Visual Studio. GCC/Clang error message is clearer: "**function template partial specialization is not allowed**"

Comment: Why function templates cannot be partially specialized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101516/why-function-template-cannot-be-partially-specialized

Comment: Do you really need recursive?

Comment: Btw your base case is wrong: it should be `<T, 1>` not `<T, 0>`, or `<T, 0>` should `return 0;`

Comment: FYI, there is a standard library algorithm [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) that will perform this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [no partial function template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101516/why-function-template-cannot-be-partially-specialized). You can either use a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses/356993#356993), which can be partially specialized:

```
template<typename T, int Size>
struct myFunctor
{
    T scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
    {
        static_assert(Size > 0,"Size must be positive!")
        return a[Size - 1]*b[Size - 1] + (myFunctor<typename T, Size - 1>::scalar_product(a, b));
    }
};
template<typename T>
struct myFunctor<T,1>
{
    T scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
    {
        return a[0] * b[0];
    }
};
```

Or you can achieve something like partial function specialization by using [std::enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/).

```
template<typename T, int Size>
typename std::enable_if<(Size>1), T>::type scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
{
    return a[Size - 1]*b[Size - 1] + (scalar_product<T, Size - 1>(a, b));
}
template<typename T, int Size>
T scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b, typename std::enable_if<(Size == 1), void*>::type x = nullptr)
{
    return a[0] * b[0];
}
```

Notice that I used 2 different ways to use std::enable_if in the 2 functions only to show that both are possible. Both functions can use enable_if on the return type like the first function does, and both of them could use them on an argument like the second function does. For additional reading see [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633/explain-c-sfinae-to-a-non-c-programmer?lq=1).

Or as a third option you can handle the specialization inside the function like this:

```
template<typename T, int Size>
T scalar_product(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
{
    static_assert(Size > 0,"Size must be positive!")
    if (Size==1)
        return a[0] * b[0];
    return a[Size - 1]*b[Size - 1] + (scalar_product<T, (Size==1) ? Size : Size - 1>(a, b));
}
```

Note that without `(Size==0) ? Size : Size - 1`, the compiler will create a function for all values of int, or die trying.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this?  http://ideone.com/nlxF0G

Comment: It should be `template<typename T, 1>` in `myFunctor` specialization.

Comment: When I use the second variant I get "fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex", which says that compiler needs specialisation, but if can't find it inside function.

Comment: Sorry for that. I added the explanation for this issue, and a workaround (use char instead of int).

Comment: @Peter “use char instead of int” is a _terrible_ workaround. Better “guard” the recursive instantiation with `scalar_product<T, (Size==1) ? Size : Size - 1>`: http://ideone.com/n5ZvKD (_edit:_ or use your `Max<Size - 1,0>::value` alternative indeed)

Comment: @ideone.com/n5ZvKD I forgot that that works. Thanks. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it should rather be `Size==1` instead of `Size==0`, and protect against `Size<=0` via a `static_assert`.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! The second variant is working now.

Comment: Yes, it should be (Size == 1)

Comment: AFAIK the string-literal in a `static_assert(constant-expression, string-literal);` is not optional.

Comment: It's been too long since I did C++. Thanks for the help guys! Anything else?