# Need help to understand the purpose of a following class

Tags: c++, templates

The friend of mine send me an interesting task:

```
template<typename T>
class TestT
{
public:
    typedef char ONE;
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } TWO;

    template<typename C>
    static ONE test(int C::*);

    template<typename C>
    static TWO test(...);
public:
    enum{ Yes = sizeof(TestT<T>::template test<T>(0)) == 1 };
    enum{ No = !Yes };
};
```

I can't compile this code with VS2013. With GCC 4.9.0 it compiles. But I can't understand what it does.

The points of interest for me:

1. How it can work if functions have a declaration only but no definition?
2. What the `TestT<T>::template test<T>(0)` is? It looks like a function call.
3. What is this `::template` means?
4. What's purpose of class above?
5. How is used principle called?
6. `int C::*` is a pointer to a `int` member, right?

Comment: *chanting* All hail the Great Old [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It does not actually call the functions, it just looks at what the `sizeof` of the return type would be.
2. It *is* a function call. See below.
3. The `template` is necessary because of the [dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) problem.
4. It tests if there can be a pointer to a data member of the type parameter. This is true for *class types* only (e.g. for `std::string` but not for `int`). You can find code like this [for example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae#Type_SFINAE) which includes something very similar to your example - under the name of `is_class`.
5. [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982808/c-sfinae-examples), which stands for "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". The reason for this name becomes obvious once you realize that the substitution of `C` for `int` will fail and thus simply cause one of the function overloads to not exist (instead of causing a compiler error and aborting compilation).
6. Yes, it is a pointer that points to an `int` inside of an object of type `C`.

Answer (score 1):

That's too many questions for a single question, but nevertheless:

1. `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand, it only determines the type. That doesn't require definitions for any functions called by the operand - the type is determined from the declaration.
2. Yes, that's a function call. If the class and function weren't templates, it would look like `TestT::test(0)`.
3. `template` is needed because the meaning of the name `test` depends on the class template parameter(s), as described in [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/).
4. It defines a constant `Yes` which is one if `T` is a class type and zero otherwise. Also a constant `No` with the logically inverted value.
5. It looks like it's intended for use in [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633), to allow templates to be partially specialised for class and non-class types. Since C++11, we can use standard traits like `std::is_class` for this purpose.
6. Yes, if `C` is a class type. Otherwise, it's a type error, so the overload taking that type is ignored, leaving just the second overload. Thus, the return type of `test` is `ONE` (with size one) if `C` is a class type, and `TWO` (with size two) otherwise; so the test for `sizeof(...) == 1` distinguishes between class and non-class types.