# SFINAE and immediate context example

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Why the following code does not generate an SFINAE error as `got_empty` will kick off many class instantiations which would fail because `my_string` does not have an empty function declared? It has something to do with the immediate context, but it is not clear why.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct my_string {    
};

template <class T, class = std::void_t<>> struct got_empty : std::false_type {};
template <class T>
struct got_empty<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
                        std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&T::empty), T>, bool>>>
    : std::true_type {};


static_assert(!got_empty<my_string>::value);
```

Comment: actually on the back of it, is it not a hard error because technically deduction happens right at &T::empty, which is the very much immediate context?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik got_empty checks if T has a function called empty and which returns bool. I was wondering why SFINAE shall work here, say what rules make it work. Now I think the fact that T::empty substitution fails right away before starting instantiating all the templates required by got_empty.

Comment: SFINAE literally stands for "substitution failure is **not an error**". What do you mean by "SFINAE error"? The compiler tries to instantiate the specialization, that doesn't work out, and it falls back to the primary template.

Comment: [Explain C++ SFINAE to a non-C++ programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633/explain-c-sfinae-to-a-non-c-programmer)

Comment: all those links I find totally unsatisfactory because they don't got into details what immediate context is and that is where SFINAE only works