# Test for existence of std::ostream operator<< via SFINAE GCC bug?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, metaprogramming, sfinae

I decided to try my own hand at a bit of [Substitution Failure Is Not A Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) (SFINAE) code to test if the global `operator<<` is defined for a custom type.

The Stack Overflow question *[SFINAE + sizeof = detect if expression compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127693/sfinae-sizeof-detect-if-expression-compiles)* already addresses testing for operator `<<` through SFINAE, but my code is slightly different and is producing a puzzling result.

Specifically, my test code below won't even compile if I try to define `operator<<` for my custom type (struct A) *after* the `test_ostr` SFINAE template code -- but, from my understanding it should work fine since it's defined *before* any actual instantiation of the test_ostr class.

[OTOH](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OTOH), it *will* compile if I define a `operator<<` for a *different* class that is not even instantiated or defined. But, then the `test_ostr` code fails to correctly find `operator<<`.

This code compiles and runs in GCC 4.4.3:

```
//#define BUG 1 // Uncomment and the program will not compile in GCC 4.4.3
//#define BUG 2 // Uncomment and the program will compile, but produces an incorrect result, claiming operator<< is not defined for A.

#include <iostream>

struct A{};
struct B{};

// If BUG is #defined, the operator<< for struct A will be defined AFTER the test_ostr code
// and if BUG <=1, then GCC 4.4.3 will not compile with the error:
// sfinae_bug.cpp:28: error: template argument 2 is invalid
#ifdef BUG
// if BUG > 1, defining the opertor << for *C*, an un-defined type, will make GCC  magically compile!?
#  if BUG > 1
  struct C;
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const C&);
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef BUG
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const A&) { return ostr; };
#endif

template<class T>
struct test_ostr
{
  template <class U, std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&, const U&) >
  struct ostrfn;
  template<class U>
  static short sfinae(ostrfn<U, &operator<< >*);
  template<class U>
  static char  sfinae(...);
  enum { VALUE = sizeof(sfinae<T>(0)) - 1 };
};

#ifdef BUG
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const A&) { return ostr; };
#endif

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "std::ostream defined for A: " << int(test_ostr<A>::VALUE) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "std::ostream defined for B: " << int(test_ostr<B>::VALUE) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output showing the bugs:

```
>c++ sfinae_bug.cpp && ./a.out 
std::ostream defined for A: 1
std::ostream defined for B: 0

>c++ -DBUG sfinae_bug.cpp && ./a.out 
sfinae_bug.cpp:28: error: template argument 2 is invalid

>c++ -DBUG=2 sfinae_bug.cpp && ./a.out 
std::ostream defined for A: 0
std::ostream defined for B: 0
```

Are these compiler bugs? Am I missing something?  Are the results different with a different compiler?

Comment: FYI, corresponding results for VS2010 are: `1 0`, error, `1 0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong, because `operator<<` is a non-dependent name. So for the case there is no `operator<<`, your template is ill-formed, and the compiler is at right to reject it at template definition time.

```
template<class U>
static short sfinae(ostrfn<U, &operator<< >*);
```

SFINAE applies when a dependent name turns out to be not declared.

Comment: Isn't the operator<< already defined for the built-in types?  Why does declaring it for the unused struct C fix the compilation for A?  Isn't still a compiler error for BUG=2?

Comment: @McKay there is no "operator<<" name declared for built-in types. For built-in types, the `<<` operator is not a actual function. All I can say is that the non-dependent lookup for `operator<<` in your code considers no function declarations that are only visible when instantiating. So in your code when `BUG` is defined, then it should either give a compiler error (BUG <= 1) or should answer with `0` (BUG > 1). (assuming that `sizeof(short)` is 2).