# Templates and preprocessing in C++

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, enums, c++03

How can someone make this code compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum E { A, B};

template< E x>
class C {
public:
    #if( x == A)
        static void foo() {
            cout << "A";
        }
    #elif( x == B)
        static void goo() {
            cout << "B";
        }
    #endif
};


int main() {
    C< A>::foo();
    C< B>::goo();

    return 0;
}

error: ‘goo’ is not a member of ‘C<(E)1u>’
```

I have two big classes which differs only a few lines, so I wanted to make enum template. The problem is that this lines have `using` keyword in them, so I don't know what to put there.

Is there some correct way to do it?

PS> I'm have to use C++03.

**EDIT**: A little clarification. I know about `template<>` construction, but I don't wanted to use it because this way I got a lot of code duplication. Maybe I can somehow make partial "template instanciation" (if this is correct term for `template<>`)?

Suppose I have two classes (and I will not have more):

```
class A {
public:
//…a lot of code…
//few lines that differs in A and B
}

class B {
//…the same mass of code…
//few lines that differs in A and B
}
```

So I decided to make template on `enum`:

```
enum E { A, B}
template< E>
class C{
//…common code…
}
```

Now I don't know what to do with this *few lines that differs in A and B*. I know that common way is to make template instanciation, but then I'll get exactly what I had with classes `A` and `B`.

From the OOP point I should use common `Base` for `A` and `B`. But the problem is that `A` and `B` is already the same. They differs only with line:

```
using CanStoreKeyValue< QString, Request>::set;
using CanStoreKeyValue< QString, Response>::set;
```

where `Response` and `Request` are typedefs. Moreover, in my code `A` and `B` are childs of the same templated abstract class. And of course they inherit it with different template param. This somehow brokes using of template enum — compiler just can't see that some virtual methods a no longer pure. So… that's why I'm asking what I'm asking. I thought that preprocessor could interact with template engine with `#if`-directives (on the end, they both are compile time processes).

Comment: Preprocessing happens before anything else. The preprocessor directives (beginning with `#`) have no idea tha `A`, `B` and `x` even exist.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why not have two classes, one with foo and one with goo?

Comment: Are you trying to get a compile time error if the method is not compatible with the parameter or are you trying to do some sort of compile time dispatching?

Comment: Your preprocessor directives (any starting with #) remove the definition of `goo()` before the compiler even sees it.

Comment: Yes, first of all I'm trying to understand if I can use preprocessor directives with template engine. Thank you guys, that you pointed that I can't do this in C++. And secondly, I trying to find the way to have `foo` in `C<A>` and `goo` in `C<B>` **without** using of the template instanciation (I mean, `template<>`) — this is because in this case I will have a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: @ValentinT. why you do not make that Request/Response type a template parameter instead of A, B?

Comment: I thought that I can't use typedefs as template parameter, so I decided to use `enum IO {In, Out}` as code for them.

Comment: @Slava, in fact I can. Thank you for your proposal, I'll use `Req` and `Resp` in change of `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want specialization, I suppose constraining the functions with [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982808/c-sfinae-examples) is an option ([Live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08740176233ad938)):

```
template <E x>
class C {
public:
    template <E y = x>
    static typename std::enable_if<y == A>::type foo() {
        cout << "A";
    }

    template <E y = x>
    static typename std::enable_if<y == B>::type goo() {
        cout << "B";
    }
};
```

But if code duplication is your only issue, use specialization and put the common code in a base class ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/269f4c0a673d5141)), it's a bit cleaner:

```
class C_base {};

template <E x>
class C : public C_base {};

template <>
class C<A> : public C_base {
public:
    static void foo() {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

template <>
class C<B> : public C_base {
public:
    static void goo() {
        cout << "B";
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Isn't std::enable_if is the C++11 construction? I didn't knew about SFINAE.

Comment: @ValentinT. Woops yes - didn't notice the C++03 tag. Will add the canonical implementation to the answer.

Comment: I find this variant of the `enable_if` as easier on the eyes, when it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d77cef8f219d21

Comment: Thank you, @MooingDuck, I think your answer was the most closest to the topic problem.

Comment: @ValentinT.: I just rewrote the code in this answer a different way.  If what I wrote was correct, then Casey's answer is more correct.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Oh! I just confused you with @Casey!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use preprocessor to achieve what you are trying to do. What you need is a template specialization:

```
enum E { A, B};

template< E x>
class C;

template <>
class C<A> {
public:
    static void foo() {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

template <>
class C<B> {
public:
    static void goo() {
        cout << "B";
    }
};
```

Your updated problem still can be resolved by template specialization:

```
enum E { A, B };

template< E x >
struct CanStoreKeyValueHelper;

template<>
struct CanStoreKeyValueHelper<A> {
    typedef CanStoreKeyValue< QString, Request>::set type;
};

template<>
struct CanStoreKeyValueHelper<B> {
    typedef CanStoreKeyValue< QString, Response>::set type;
};

template< E x>
class SuperPuperBigClass {
public:
    typedef typename CanStoreKeyValueHelper<x>::type set;
    ...
};
```

But it is not clear why you do not make it as simple as:

```
template<class T>
class SuperPuperBigClass {
public:
    typedef typename CanStoreKeyValue<QString, T>::set set;
};
```

and instantiate it with Request and Response type

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there is some way in C++ to have `foo` in `C<A>` and `goo` in `C<B>` without using of "template instanciating" (I don't know, is it correct term for `template<>`)?

Comment: I don't want to use `template<>` construction because this way I will have a lot of code duplication.

Comment: @ValentinT.: Move the duplicate code into a shared base class.  Alternatively, one could use `std::enable_if`, but that can be complex.

Comment: I have two classes inherits from the same templated abstract class with different template arguments. They already are inherited from the same base and differs with some `using` lines and pure virtuals implementation. And compiler somehow can't see that they implement the abstract base. So, I just wanted the construction analog for preprocessor `#if` construction, but for template. And I have to use C++03, so I believe `std::enable_if` is not my case.