# How to use traits to know if a type can be use with cout

Tags: c++, std, traits

I'd like use "traits" in order to write a function which prints all values of a list,

```
template<typename T>
    void print(std::list<T> l) 
    { 
      for (auto item : l)
        cout << item; cout << endl; 
    };
```

I also tried :

Sorry, my question was not so clear cause i'm just begining with some new c++ features.
I tried something like :

```
template<class T>
enable_if_t<is_convertible_v<T,std::string>> print(std::list<T> l) 
{
    for (auto item : l) std::cout << item << endl; 
};
```

but not working, visual studio tells there's no operator << for std::tring ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "traits", do you mean the "concepts" feature in C++20?

Comment: `The type T must be convertible to std::string` Why?

Comment: Why must the type be convertible to `std::string`? `std::ostream& operator(std::ostream&, SomeType const&)` can be implemented without `SomeType` being convertible to `std::string`. Furthermore if you pass a type without this operator being available, you'll get a compiler error. The behaviour isn't really much different to anything you could do with the typetraits library or similar features.

Comment: I guess you want to do a SFINAE on `decltype(cout << l.front())` ?

Comment: Your question title asks how to find if it a type *would be* printable with `cout` but the question body implies that `T` is already printable with `cout`. It isn't clear what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to `cout` a `std::list<T>`, you need no traits. Just write

```
template<typename T> void print(std::list<T> const& list) {
  for (auto&& t: list) std::cout << t;
}
```

and the compiler will produce an error if anything doesn't work.

#### Don't go for the following as long as the above solution is enough

If you want to build compile-time logic based on the "printability" of `T` (something SFINAE-like), just use a C++20 [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template<typename T> concept Ostreamable = requires(T t) { std::cout << t; };

template<Ostreamable T> void print(std::list<T> const& list) {
  for (auto&& t: list) std::cout << t;
}
```

If you don't have C++20, you can hack your way through in the good old manner:

```
template<typename T, typename = void> auto constexpr ostreamable_v = false;
template<typename T> auto constexpr ostreamable_v<
  T, std::void_t<decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>
> = true;

template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<ostreamable_v<T>> print(std::list<T> const& list) {
  for (auto&& t: list) std::cout << t;
}
```

The general pre-C++20 idea is deliberately breaking the more prioritized signatures which don't match your predicate, see [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460808/12816539).

Comment: Hi, it's exactly what i was look for !