# Does this line declare a function? C++

Tags: c++, function-declaration

I was reading litb's question about SFINAE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822059/sfinae-with-invalid-function-type-or-array-type-parameters) and I was wondering exactly what his code is declaring. A simpler (without the templates) example is below:

```
int (&a())[2];
```

What exactly is that declaring? What is the role of the &? To add to my confusion, if I declare the following instead

```
int b()[2];
```

I get an error about declaring a function that returns an array, while the first line has no such error (therefore, one would think the first declaration is **not** a function). However, if I try to assign a

```
a = a;
```

I get an error saying I'm attempting to assign the function a... so now it **is** a function. What exactly is this thing?

Comment: I used that rather weird construct to see what function was called. sizeof(a()) will give you sizeof(int[2]) . The other function would be declared as  int(&a())[1]; and if that one was called, it would give sizeof(int[1]). It makes use of the fact that for any T, sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's these awesome programs called cdecl and c++decl. They're very helpful for figuring out complicated declarations, especially for the byzantine forms that C and C++ use for function pointers.

```
tyler@kusari ~ $ c++decl
Type `help' or `?' for help
c++decl> explain int (&a())[2]
declare a as function returning reference to array 2 of int
c++decl> explain int b()[2]
declare b as function returning array 2 of int
```

a returns a reference, b does not.

Comment: wow, those programs are useful. I don't suppose a Windows port exists?

Comment: I don't know of a canonical version of cdecl for Windows (although of course you could always use the Linux version through Cygwin), but if you google for "cdecl.zip" it seems to pull up a few windows ports that various people have done.

Comment: That is actually very useful.

Comment: As far as I can see, the .zip dates back to 1987, which means it's probably not very useful for C++ syntax... :)
But thanks, I'll check it out. Or just use it through Cygwin

Comment: ran into those programs a while ago. legendary!

Comment: @jalf: c++ on winders? cast away your shackles!

Comment: @Matt: I love when people claim that the way to "cast away your shackles" is to limit your options. Because yes, I'm so much more free and unshackled if I target Linux than I am if I target both Linux and Windows. ;)

Comment: C++ does not allow functions returning arrays, though.

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, you may find this link helpful when you have a particularly difficult C/C++ declaration to decipher:

[How To Read C Declarations](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations)

For completeness, I will repeat what others have said to directly answer your question.

```
int (&a())[2];
```

...declares *a* to be a zero-argument function which returns a reference to an integer array of size 2.  (Read the basic rules on the link above to have a clear understanding of how I came up with that.)

```
int b()[2];
```

...declares *b* to be a zero-argument function which returns an integer array of size two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: C++ does not allow functions returning arrays, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (&a())[2];
```

It declares a symbol `a` that is a function that takes no arguments and returns a reference to a two-element array of integers.

```
 int b()[2];
```

This declares a symbol `b` that is a function that takes no arguments and returns a two-element array of integers... this is impossible by the design of the language.

It is relatively simple: get an operator precedence chart, start the symbol name (`a`) and start applying the operators as you see from their precedence. Write down after each operation applied.