# complex C++ template syntax

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

After joining SO, I am frequently seeing this kind of syntax whenever I open topics discussing templates. I tried searching on google, but in vain.

```
template<typename T>
char (&f(T[1]))[1]; //what is it? what is the use of '[]' brackets and the integer in it?

template<typename T>
char (&f(...))[2]; //not this either

int main() { char c[sizeof(f<void()>(0)) == 2]; } // and this?
```

From here : [SFINAE with invalid function-type or array-type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822059/sfinae-with-invalid-function-type-or-array-type-parameters)

Please explain the 3 lines where I have put comments. I particularly want to understand the syntax. Can we use such syntax in templates only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two are equivalent

```
// 1
template<typename T>
char (&f(...))[2]; 

// 2
typedef char rettype[2];
template<typename T>
rettype &f(...);
```

You may have have seen that pattern before with function pointers

```
char (*XXX)();
```

Now just replace the `()` with `[N]` to create an array instead of a function part, and replace `*` by `&` to create a reference instead of a pointer, and replace the `XXX` by a function declarator. Then you get a function that returns a reference to an array of size `N`.

---

You may want to look into `man signal`, which contains a similarly typed function declaration. If you take out the inner declarator that actually declares the function, you get the same pattern

```
void (* signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)) )(int);
//      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ take out that
```

It will return a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`, as described in that manpage.

---

The following is just a way to yield a compiler error *if* some condition is not satisfied. *If* the test `foo == 2` turns out to be `false`, the array created is of zero size, which is illegal in C++, and will earn a compile time error. If it evaluates to true, nothing happens except the array being declared.

```
char c[some silly condition here];
```

Comment: nice explanation, thanks. if that silly condition creates array of zero size, then why did you put that condition?

Comment: Because the purpose is to use the array size's invalidity to prevent compilation of some particular piece of code - for example, an instantiation of some template for particular types which are to be handled specially.

Comment: @Pointer: it's a concept known as a "compile time assert". The "normal" `assert()` checks a boolean condition at runtime. With this method, you can check a boolean condition at compile time. For instance, `char c[CHAR_BIT==8]` makes it explicit that your program can't deal with compilers that have `CHAR_BIT==9`

Comment: @karl, @MSalters. please also explain what does 'T[5]' mean? is not it invalid also? say, T is int, then what would int[5] mean? i tried writing a `func(int[5] arg)`, it gave error.